# Java simple web browser weird output

Tags: java, browser

To learn Networking in Java, I followed a tutorial to create a new web browser in NetBeans. Here is the code in `ReadFile` class:

```
package WebBrowser;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Siddharth Venu
 * 
 */
public class ReadFile extends JFrame{
    private JTextField addressBar;
    private JEditorPane display;

    //constructor
    public ReadFile(){
        super("Sid Browser");

        addressBar=new JTextField("Enter address");
        //lambda expression instead of anonymous class
        addressBar.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            loadData(event.getActionCommand());
        });
        add(addressBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        display = new JEditorPane();
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.addHyperlinkListener((HyperlinkEvent event) -> {
            if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)
                loadData(event.getURL().toString());
        });
        add(new JScrollPane(display), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(500,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //load the data to display on the screen
    private void loadData(String address){
        try{
            display.setPage(address);
            addressBar.setText(address);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code in the `Main` class:

```
package WebBrowser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author Siddharth Venu
 * 
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ReadFile browser=new ReadFile();
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I then ran the `Main` class, at beginning, as it is not displaying any data from a website, it is looking good with address bar on the top. But when I enter an URL, say `http://google.com`, it displays weird output as in the following image.
[image: Display output of my browser]
Why exactly is this happening? The weird blue background and misaligned Google logo.

[Edit] I got to know that the `setPage` method can only handle HTML, plain text or RTF and not js. But it should at least display the HTML part without the weird blue screen na? PS: The blue screen is appearing in other sites like facebook too.

Comment: I'm no expert but is it not entirely out of question that Google uses Javascript on their front page?

Comment: I am sorry not to be clear, but I am making a browser, not building Google's front page. The `display.setPage` will parse html, js and css for displaying it(I think so, please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Oh I am sorry, it seems js and css are not supported by the `setPage` method. At least the html should be shown properly na? without the weird blue screen. Check it out here- https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=25&video=17766. This guy runs it without any problems.

Comment: @Lagomorph question updated. please check

Comment: Have you tried a very simple page without js and css? Only that I wouldn't assume that's the problem if somebody else managed to make it work, with the same pages, using the same method. Have you used exactly the same code and libraries?

Comment: The Java Swing JEditorPane only resolves HTML 3.2.  JavaFX can handle more recent HTML.

Comment: Thanks all of you, it works on simple pages like bare to the bones website as mentioned by @Lagomorph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your browser. I'm getting the same results on pages with html5, javascript and css like `google.com` or `facebook.com`.

But when I use bare to the bones website like [this](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node259.html) it obviously works. So I must assume that the issue was the lack of support for these technologies in this simple browser.

*As for the guy in the [video linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mHqkbt0w6Y) he used bare html google webpage which I was unable to find or read out from the video (or made the video some time ago). People in the youtube comment section were addressing your issue as well. They were describing it as a lack of support for html5 in Swing. However some managed to make it work properly in JavaFX.*